# ¿ El lenguaje de programacion afecta el rendimiento de google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

Google App Engine puede ser utilizado con Java, PHP, Python y Go. El rendimiento de las web apps varia de acuerdo al lenguaje que se utilice ? o una vez que el codigo entra a los servidores de google no importa en que lenguaje fue programado, el rendimiento es el rendimiento que da google a App Engine.

Comment: Por experiencia, sé que cada lenguaje tiene pros y contras para algunas operaciones debido a su implementación por ejemplo PHP es más lento por ser un lenguaje script que cualquier lenguaje que ejecuta componentes compilados como Java. Si las operaciones que realizas en tu aplicación son mínimas o no existen tantos usuarios concurrentes entonces esa diferencia será irrelevante. En cambio, si vas a proveer servicios que acceden a múltiples fuentes de datos y que los servicios serán accedidos entre 1 y 10 millones de veces cada 6 horas, pues allí la diferencia de rendimiento será abismal.

Comment: Para referencia de performance web podés consultar [Web Framework Benchmarks](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/). De todas formas como implementes tu solución (arquitectura + desarrollo) puede hacer variar la performance de la misma.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza para PHP tenemos cosas como la [HHVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HipHop_Virtual_Machine), el bebé de Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando Google lanzó App Engine en 2008 tenía soporte solo para Python, luego agregó Java, Go, PHP y ahora como las Managed VMs cualquier lenguaje.

Cuando una trabaja en App Engine siente que fue diseñado para trabajar con Python, además la documentación y solución a problemas que te surjan es mucho más amplia en Python y Java.

Comment: Es un dato muy interesante, pero técnicamente hablando no responde a la pregunta. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Una ventaja de un lenguaje de script es que permite la carga dinámica/perezoso del código que a su vez puede reducir el tiempo de arranque y el uso total de memoria de una instancia GAE.

SO Inglés:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34635012/what-determines-start-up-time-of-dynamic-instance-and-can-it-vary-between-weeks/34637044#34637044
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33453441/app-engine-few-big-scripts-or-many-small-ones/33457227#33457227

(Por favor, disculpe la respuesta corta - soy solo un principiante en Español)

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo ver [este vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLriM2krw2E), donde hace una comparación de las fortalezas y debilidades de cada lenguaje en app engine, básicamente dice que uses el lenguaje en el que seas mas productivo, pero en mi experiencia Python y Java hacen uso de las funcionalidades de app engine con mayor anticipación que PHP y Go, pero por otro lado Go es el único lenguaje que es compilado por lo que ganarías un poco de velocidad ahí (en el vídeo dice que no esta 100% listo para producción, pero toma en cuenta que es del 2013)

No debes de perder de vista que al ser computo en la nube, por lo que la aplicación debe escalar conforme crece tu base de usuarios o el computo que realizas, mas que en lenguaje en si mismo tendría un mayor impacto la arquitectura de tu aplicación y sobre todo el tipo de búsquedas que haces en tus datos, pon mucho énfasis en conocer a fondo [NDB](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/) y la relación entre las entidades, ya que esto hará mayor diferencia que la selección de python vs java vs Go

Answer (score 1):

En base a mi experiencia con App Engine Google recomienda utilizar Python o Java no tanto por performance si no por la integracion y documentacion, incluso vas a encontar tutoriales en [Udacity](http://www.udacity.com) que te llevan de la mano usando cualquiera de los dos.

En mi caso he utilizado Java con Spring MVC y todo funciona perfecto, pero debes seguir ciertas [buenas practicas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/spring_optimization) cuando utilizas frameworks como Spring ya que por la arquitectura misma de App Engine que genera instancias de tu app al vuelo dependiendo de la demanda, requiere que los tiempos de inicialización sean cortos para no afectar a los usuarios al momento de crear una instancia nueva para balancear las peticiones.

Go es un lenguaje que google esta empujando y que debe ser bueno, pero creo que no existe documentación suficiente aun y uno de los puntos claves es que tan productivo puedes llegar a ser con un lenguaje u otro.

Al final todo se reduce a que tan bien escribas tu código y las buenas practicas que sigas, porque uses el lenguaje que uses puedes terminar con un producto indeseado y problemas de performance.

Comment: Hay que tener en cuenta que el hecho de estar en la nube no garantiza que el lenguaje de programación utilizado no será al final un cuello de botella. Un ejemplo de esto es Netflix que cambió su arquitectura de servicios de Ruby (lenguaje script) hacia Scala (lenguaje compilado y que corre sobre JVM) y su plataforma ahora tiene mayor soporte de usuarios y es más flexible. Mi recomendación es: si vas a hacer cosas pequeñas, trabaja con lo que te sientas más cómodo y puedas producir más rápido, conforme vayas evolucionando, ve madurando el grupo de tecnologías que utilizas.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, pero en este caso, Google controla cada aspecto de los lenguajes que permite utilizar y aquellas librerías o clases que podrían representar un riesgo en cuanto a seguridad o performance no se pueden utilizar, aquí puedes ver las clases que son permitidas para java (whitelist): https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist?csw=1

Comment: Creo que no entiendes mi punto. Hay lenguajes donde el compilador puede realizar mejoras adicionales del código en tiempo de ejecución p.e. JVM, y por eso tienen mucho mejor performance que lenguajes script. No se trata de ver alguna whitelist o cosas así, ya es algo donde ese esfuerzo no llega a más. Ahora, para comprobar realmente cuál sería el mejor o peor, se deberían hacer pruebas de estrés implementando un grupo de funcionalidades en los lenguajes a evaluar (mismo algoritmo, etc) y conversar con los resultados. Aunque la experiencia en muchos lugares indica que compilado > script